# How to float span properly

Tags: html, css

I am developing this site http://indigonightlife.com/ The second section down is This Weeks Events.  To the right of that heading is an image of the 5 little blue lines.  The problem Im having is I cant get it to float to the right side of the container.  As it is now, its in the middle of the container.  Ive tried all kinds of combos of floats, clearfixes, and such but I cant get it to stay to the right.  The section below titled Resident and Guest DJs has the same image but its floated fine.  Not sure what the difference is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a class instead of an id for `bluestripes`

Comment: Alright I switched that to class and it still looks the same

Comment: Adding "float: right;" to the span works for me in Opera 12. (I just edited with an inline style attribute, but should just work fine if you add that style to the class.)

Comment: I have this for the span css now and it doesnt appear to be working.  Am I missing something?  `.bluestripes{
float: right;
display: block;
width:134px;
height: 34px;
overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: Im on Chrome and FF looks the same BTW

Comment: In the future, you should try to isolate the problem and post that as code here, and generally a demo (with jsfiddle or a similar tool) helps this. You'll want to strip down the code to the bare minimum to recreate the problem so any answers can be useful to people with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "height: 460px" from #homewidgets.

That box is the cause to the image not being floated to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Your "homewidgets" div is overflowing and preventing the image from floating all the way to the right. In style.css line 245 remove the height attribute:

```
#homewidgets {
    float: right;
    height: 460px;
    width: 307px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.heading {
font-family: neuro;
font-size: 37px;
color: white;
width: 800px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.bluestripes{display: inline-block;
width: 132px;
}
```